# Is there a "standard" way to implement Software Activation for .NET?

Tags: .net, activation

I've been looking at software activation systems for .NET and frankly found the websites out there underwhelming.  I'm wondering if there's a "standard" way to do it in .NET?  If not, does anyone with experience of them have a recommendation?

I understand the arguments for and against activation systems, but still need to evaluate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework doesn't have any built in support for software activation - you'll have to purchase a licensing tool from a vendor. Microsoft got into this game a while back (MS SLP) but didn't have much success and sold it off to http://www.inishtech.com/.

We sell a licensing solution that you should have a look at when you're researching vendors: [DeployLX Software Protection System](http://xheo.com). We've been around for a long time and have a highly refined activation system.

Answer (score 1):

The common (not standard) way is to retrieve a machine-locked license from a license service. The license service stores a record of how many machines have asked for licenses for the same "license ID". You can then limit the number of activations for each "ID". The common way to store the ID, number of activations is RSA.

If you want to use a ready implementation of the above idea, take a look at [CryptoLicensing](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm)

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP, the developers of CryptoLicensing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of third party products. They all work more or less the same. The one that I have used is InstallKey from [www.lomacons.com](http://www.lomacons.com)  It's simple, well written and comes with excellent documenttaion.